# A lattice in $ \operatorname{SL}_n $ is Ad-irreducible

Tags: lie-groups, lattices

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$Let $ G $ be a noncompact simple Lie group. For example $ \SL_n $. Let $ \Gamma $ be a lattice in $ G $. Consider the action of $ \Gamma $ on the Lie algebra of $ G $ by conjugation. Is this representation of $ \Gamma $ always irreducible?

For example, I think it is true that all lattices in $ \SL_2(\mathbb{R}) $ and $ \SL_2(\mathbb{C}) $  are Ad-irreducible.

Comment: Well we do know that $Ad(G)$ acts irreducibly, and $\Gamma$ is Zariski dense by Borel's density theorem, so yes.
Probably one can get a more ``geometric'' direct proof in several cases, for example for $SL_{2}(Z)$, one has the raising/lowering operators given by the unipotents...

Comment: @Asaf, isn't [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431466/a-lattice-in-operatornamesl-n-is-ad-irreducible#comment1110521_431466) an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the request to post it as an answer.

Notice that the Ad representation is a polynomial representation into $\operatorname{GL}(\operatorname{Lie}(G))$.
We do know that $\operatorname{Ad}(G)$ acts irreducibly, and $\Gamma$ is Zariski dense by Borel's density theorem. Hence $\operatorname{Ad}\rvert_{\Gamma}$ is also irreducible.